# How do you grep two hyhpens only?

Tags: grep, regular-expression

After looking for solutions online I can grep for two hyphens without issue with `grep -r "\-\-"` or `grep -r \\ --`. But the files grep searches sometimes have lines full of hyphens, for example in comments, e.g. `/*--------- comment ----- */`. I want to grep to return cases where only two hyphens are next to each other. E.g. `--` and not `---`. Ideally I could use `-w` but I'm not having luck with this.

And a second piece of the puzzle is, if somehow I can grep for only two consecutive hyphens `--`, I want to find the pattern as though it was a perfect match like `-w` would do. So something like `i--;` would not feature as a result. But `i --` would. Maybe there's a simple solution but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least if you have GNU grep, you could use PCRE [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match a pair of hyphens that are neither preceded nor followed by a hyphen:

```
grep -P '(?<!-)--(?!-)' file
```

or

```
grep -Pw '(?<!-)--(?!-)' file
```